# Can you replace the vector an array_view is bound to?

Tags: c++, vector, c++-amp

I know that it is good for performance to keep the views alive and reuse them. Problem is, the pipeline I'm working within doesn't always preserve the memory locations of the source data vectors. At that point I'm forced to create new views and ditch the old ones but I'm trying to avoid that.

From what I can tell, there shouldn't really be any hardcore link between the vector and the view, as long as the vector is of the same size and type I can't see a reason why it couldn't be switched out.

So is there a way to select the vector outside the array_view constructor? Or maybe you could change the data location of the object vector itself?

Also I'm using quite a few temporary buffer views, when their array_view's get destroyed it hangs the computer for a few moments as its syncinc the data. I don't need the data so could I destroy them without syncing?

Comment: I figured out the "Also" part, the hang was because I only dispatched gpu executions but didn't wait for them to finish so as I was exiting the program with a bunch of things still queued up, it somehow hangs things.. whatever, undefined behavior I guess. Also the temporary buffers can be discarded(and should be or they will force sync which also hangs at the end) with the .discard method, fascinating! Still wondering about swapping out the source for array_view data though.